# Speed up Excel array formula to find unique distinct values

Tags: arrays, excel, performance, formula

I have a workbook in which a variable number of rows of data (one per employee) are entered each week on one sheet (DATA ENTRY), and then stored on another sheet (LOG) with the help of a macro that is executed every time the file is saved.

To be able to then retrieve and review employee data for a specific week, I need a column of helper cells in which all the unique distinct dates (weeks) are listed.

I currently do this with the following array formula:

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$1600, MATCH(0,COUNTIF($K$1:K1, $B$2:$B$1600), 0)),"")}
```

This all works brilliantly, except that I found that this one specific formula slows my file down tremendously. When the file is saved (which triggers data to be copied over to the LOG sheet), it can take up to 10 seconds to process. When this array formula is disabled, it is pretty much instantaneous.

Limiting it to run over 1600 rows helped significantly (it took much longer before when I had it set to 20.000), but it is still not enough and I can't really have this check less than 1600 rows.

Any creative solutions to either make this formula run faster, or to get to the same result (a list of unique distinct dates from a large list of dates) without using an array formula?

Thanks!

Comment: Use a dictionary object in a UDF.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Power Query (Get & Transform Data) to populate your list of unique dates.